# Trying to create a C# program that uses auto-implemented properties, overrides ToString(), and uses a child class

Tags: c#, class, oop, inheritance, overriding

I'm going to try to be as clear as possible, but bear with me.
I need to make a program that:

1. Create a class named LetterDemo that instantiates objects of two classes (named Letter and Certified Letter)
2. The Letter class includes auto-implemented properties for name of the letter recipient and the date is was mailed.
3. In the Letter class, also create a ToString() method that overrides the Object class's ToString() method and retuns a string that contains the name of the class (using GetType() and the Letter's data field values.
4. Create a child class named CertifiedLetter that contains an auto-implemented property that holds a tracking number for the letter. (I am assuming this would be given if the user indicates that the letter is certified.)

I have most of it figured out but I am stuck on the CertifiedLetter and tracking number part.
Any help with clarification of how to use a child class and integrate a method within it would be a life saver. Thank you!

```
//using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using static System.Console;

class LetterDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Letter newLetter = new Letter();

        WriteLine("Please enter name of recipient >> ");
        string inputName = ReadLine();
        newLetter.Name = inputName;

        WriteLine("Please enter the date letter was mailed >> ");
        string inputDate = ReadLine();
        newLetter.DateMailed = inputDate;

        WriteLine("Is letter certified? Y or N >> ");
        string isCertified = ReadLine();

        if (isCertified.Length > 1)
        {
            WriteLine("Please enter only 'Y' or 'N' >> ");
        }
        else
        {
           // Send to CertifiedLetter
                }
        WriteLine(newLetter.ToString());

    }
    class Letter
    {
        private string name;
        private string dateMailed;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DateMailed { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
              return GetType() + " is being sent to " + Name + " one the day of " + DateMailed + ".";
            
        }
    }
    class CertfiedLetter : Letter
    {
        public static int TrackingNumber()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int newNum = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
            int trackingNumber = newNum;
            return trackingNumber;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this question just wants the class to have: `public string TrackingNumber { get; set; }`

Comment: @shingo thanks for the advice! could you clarify which class should have this property? I'm guessing maybe the parent class?

Comment: Of course it refers to CertifiedLetter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Auto-Implemented Properties: You've correctly implemented auto-implemented properties for Name and DateMailed in the Letter class. You'll want to do something similar for the TrackingNumber in the CertifiedLetter class.
- CertifiedLetter Class: The CertifiedLetter should inherit from Letter and add an additional property for the tracking number. The TrackingNumber should not be a method but a property. You can generate a tracking number in the constructor of the CertifiedLetter.
- Handling Certified Letters: In the Main method, you need to create an instance of CertifiedLetter when the user indicates that the letter is certified. This instance should also have a name and a date, in addition to a tracking number.
- ToString Method in CertifiedLetter: Override the ToString method in CertifiedLetter to include information about the tracking number.

For example like this:

```
class LetterDemo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WriteLine("Please enter name of recipient >> ");
        string inputName = ReadLine();

        WriteLine("Please enter the date letter was mailed >> ");
        string inputDate = ReadLine();

        WriteLine("Is letter certified? Y or N >> ");
        string isCertified = ReadLine();

        Letter letter;

        if (isCertified.Equals("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            letter = new CertifiedLetter
            {
                Name = inputName,
                DateMailed = inputDate
            };
        }
        else
        {
            letter = new Letter
            {
                Name = inputName,
                DateMailed = inputDate
            };
        }

        WriteLine(letter.ToString());
    }
}

class Letter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DateMailed { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GetType().Name + " is being sent to " + Name + " on the day of " + DateMailed + ".";
    }
}

class CertifiedLetter : Letter
{
    public int TrackingNumber { get; }

    public CertifiedLetter()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        TrackingNumber = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + " The tracking number is " + TrackingNumber + ".";
    }
}
```

Edit based on your comment:

You could print the letter properties more directly:

```
static void Main()
{
    WriteLine("Please enter name of recipient >> ");
    string inputName = ReadLine();

    WriteLine("Please enter the date letter was mailed >> ");
    string inputDate = ReadLine();

    WriteLine("Is letter certified? Y or N >> ");
    string isCertified = ReadLine();

    if (isCertified.Equals("Y", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        // Create and display a CertifiedLetter
        CertifiedLetter certifiedLetter = new CertifiedLetter
        {
            Name = inputName,
            DateMailed = inputDate
        };
        WriteLine(certifiedLetter.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        // Create and display a regular Letter
        Letter letter = new Letter
        {
            Name = inputName,
            DateMailed = inputDate
        };
        WriteLine(letter.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {

        IInputForLetter inputLetterConsoleSource = new InputForLetterConsoleSource();
        ICertificationResolver certificationResolver = new CertificationFactory();
        inputLetterConsoleSource.ObtainInputValues(out string nameInput, out string dateInput, out string messageInput, out string certificationInput);
        Letter letter = certificationResolver.CreateLetter(certificationInput);
        letter.Name = nameInput;
        letter.DateMailed = dateInput;
        letter.LetterMessage = messageInput;
        Console.WriteLine(letter.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(letter.LetterMessage);
    }

    public class InputForLetterConsoleSource : IInputForLetter
    {
        public void ObtainInputValues(out string nameInput, out string dateInput, out string messageInput, out string certificationInput)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter name of recipient >> ");
            nameInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the date letter was mailed >> ");
            dateInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Please provide a letter message >> ");
            messageInput = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Is letter certified? Y or N >> ");
            certificationInput = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class CertificationFactory : ICertificationResolver
    {
        public Letter CreateLetter(string certificationInput)
        {
            Letter letter;
            switch (certificationInput)
            {
                case "Y":
                    {
                        letter = new Letter(new Certification());
                        break;
                    }
                case "N":
                    {
                        letter = new Letter(new NoCertification());

                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException("The program only accepts 'Y' or 'N' as certification input");
                    }
            }

            return letter;
        }
    }

    public class Letter
    {
        private readonly ICertifiedLetterHandler _certifiedLetterHandler;

        public Letter(ICertifiedLetterHandler certifiedLetterHandler)
        {
            _certifiedLetterHandler = certifiedLetterHandler;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string DateMailed { get; set; }

        public string LetterMessage { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Name: " + Name + " mailed: " + DateMailed + " trackingNumber: " + _certifiedLetterHandler.GetCertificationTrackingNumber();
        }
    }

    public class Certification : ICertifiedLetterHandler
    {
        string _trackingNumber;

        public Certification()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int newNum = rnd.Next(1000, 9999);
            _trackingNumber = newNum.ToString();
        }

        public string GetCertificationTrackingNumber()
        {
            return _trackingNumber;
        }
    }

    public class NoCertification : ICertifiedLetterHandler
    {
        public string GetCertificationTrackingNumber()
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }

    public interface ICertifiedLetterHandler
    {
        string GetCertificationTrackingNumber();
    }

    public interface ICertificationResolver
    {
        Letter CreateLetter(string certificationInput);
    }

    public interface IInputForLetter
    {
        void ObtainInputValues(out string nameInput, out string dateInput, out string messageInput, out string certificationInput);
    }
}
```

You should not be using inheritence. Inheritence is a deprecated concept.
Composition is superior for readability, and testability.

There is no scenario where inheritence is better than composition in OOP.
So using inheritence, is a mistake at the fundamental level.

It's like learning to hammer a nail in with a rock, when the world has be flooded with hammers, and yet, you aren't learning to use a hammer, but being taught the rock.

You should be using Composition over inherirance, "SOLID" and clean code.
These three will lift your code quality to a level where you can actually work with others, help you keep your code low coupled so it is easy to test and discuss with others (Maintainability), and easy to cover with unit tests, integration tests and end to end tests.

Comment: Thank you for this advice! I will keep this in mind as I get further in my learning. Unfortunately, for this particular project, inheritance is the required implementation

Comment: If this is a school project, please ask your teacher, why you aren't being taught composition rather than inheritance? 
Please refer him to me, if he gives you any nasty feedback from said question. You can have my private email, in a DM, if needed.

If we interviewed a new programmer where I work, he would get rejected if he didn't know composition was superior.

Comment: When something is dysfunctionally often used as a 'one size fits all approach', replacing it by yet another 'one size fits all approach' seems to constantly cause new issues though. By practicing a bit with both you can figure out when they are more applicable right? When you've used both a rock as a hammer once, you know what's the fundament of what you want to do with the nail. Composition is cool though

Comment: @Miles Not really. There is NEVER an advantage to using inheritence. No scenario. 
The boilerplate is roughly the same, but the testablity, is always a problem in inheritence. 

Of course, the scenario that invalidates that claim is to claim you WISH to write untestable, unmaintable code, yes, then inheritence is better. But then we also have nothing left to say to each other.

Comment: You're clearly on a mission, very nice

Comment: @Miles no mission, just facts. If you can mention any scenario, where inheritencce is a better choice, I am all ears.